# Groovy Gorilla, Raspberry Pi and Mathematica

Tags: raspberrypi, 20.10, mathematica

I saw [this article](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/10/ubuntu-groovy-gorilla-adds-raspberry-pi-as-a-first-class-citizen/#p3). Raspberry Pi users can run a Mathematica copy bundled with it. Does that mean that Ubuntu 20.10 users will be able to run Mathematica on their computers?

Answer (score 1):

No, Mathematica is only bundled with [Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-os/). The version of Ubuntu released for the Raspberry Pi is almost same as the regular version of Ubuntu (but optimized for Pi), which does not include Mathematica.

You can still technically install the ARM version of Mathematica on it, but it is not included for free.

Comment: The key is Mathematica is not free or open source software. One has to pay for it unless one runs the Raspberry Pi OS on a Raspberry Pi.